# how to create domain.com/tag/mytag in joomla 2.5

Tags: .htaccess, url, joomla

I am using joomla 2.5 and I installed my "PLG_CONTENT_SHOWTAGS" plugin

this plugin is creatign url for tags like bottom:

```
http://domain.com/component/search/keyword
```

how can i use this like bottom:

```
http://domain.com/tag/keyword
```

can i use .htaccess?

I don't know what I most pun in htaccess file.

Comment: First somewhere on a hidden menu make a link a search page with the alias of tag. That will get rid of the `component/search`  segments and give you the `/tag/` segment. However I'd really use finder which gives you a lot more options for saved and custom search links.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the basic syntax of how to forward from one url to another. The below has a few sections

- **(.+)**: This matches any character multiple times. *ex: tag/keyword+search*
- **$1**: This would take what was after `tag/` and append it to the required url. *ex: component/search/keyword+search*

More information on rewriting can be found on the [Apache website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

---

```
 RewriteEngine On
 #Look for the word "tag" followed by a slash, and then the keyword
 RewriteRule ^tag/(.+)$ component/search/$1 [L]

 # Variations of above rule depending on server setup
 # RewriteRule ^tag/(.+)$ /component/search/$1 [L]
 # RewriteRule ^tag/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/component/search/$1 [L]
```

Comment: He's really asking a Joomla-specific question.

Comment: But he does ask if he can do it with htaccess. With Joomla he could use one of the many redirect/rewrite modules that are out there